# MyspaceID login system

Tags: php, myspace

I really would like to integrate the Myspace ID platform on my site using PHP, instead of allowing users to sign in to my site anytime with there myspace ID I am planning on just using it 1 time on signup process to allow them to import profile data from there myspace to my network.

I have note been able to find any good example code for doing any kind of myspace integration, has anyone done this and care to share any info on the issue please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySpace is an OpenID provider. What you're looking for is an OpenID consumer library.

This one turned up as the first result on Google though there are many more out there: [PHP OpenID Library](http://openidenabled.com/php-openid/)

This let's people not only use MySpace, but Google, AOL, Yahoo, Flickr and innumerable other sites to sign into yours. I use it regularly. Even Stack Overflow uses OpenID sign in. Great stuff!

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to use JanRain - they handle login for multiple networks including MySpace, Facebook, Twitter, Yahoo!, etc.

http://www.janrain.com/